# How to provision a AWS EC2 server through REST API in C#?

Tags: rest, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

I have referred the AWS EC2 server provision document.
1. Im unable to create the signature from Access key and secret key.
what is the API (needed parameters, headers) to  generate a signature? and how to provision a server ? can any one explain me please?

Answer (score 0):

would you consider finding this out from the Getting Started with AWS SDK for .NET:

http://aws.amazon.com/developers/getting-started/net/

It looks pretty straightforward and in my humble opinion it is a good practice not to reinvent any activities related to security (such as authentication or authorization) and use the recommended framework/SDK.

Regarding launching an instance, please refer to the guide in this page:

http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSSdkDocsNET/latest/V3/DeveloperGuide/run-instance.html

Comment: I want to do in REST API.I have a API to launch a instance while launching I need to be pass the signature. From where i can get signature ? Please giude me. Thanks in advance

Comment: If you need to use REST query API then this page might give you more details. For version 4 signature : http://docs.aws.amazon.com/general/latest/gr/sigv4_signing.html . For version 2 signature: http://docs.aws.amazon.com/general/latest/gr/signature-version-2.html . As you can see it is not pretty straightforward. Basically you would have to create a canonical string of your request, hash it to create a string that you would have to sign. After that, calculate the signature string, and attach it to the request that you would send to API endpoint. Good luck!

Comment: static byte[] getSignatureKey(String key, String dateStamp, String regionName, String serviceName)
        {
            byte[] kSecret = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(("AWS4" + key).ToCharArray());
            byte[] kDate = HmacSHA256(dateStamp, kSecret);
            byte[] kRegion = HmacSHA256(regionName, kDate);
            byte[] kService = HmacSHA256(serviceName, kRegion);
            byte[] kSigning = HmacSHA256("aws4_request", kService);
          return kSigning;
        } Im using this method to create a signature.while using this signature in endpoint its showing signture not matching.